# resetting element.selectedIndex with each dynamic change

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a dynamic selector that generates options from a google sheet based on another elements value. For example, if the parent value is equal to "A", then the reasons on google sheet "A" are populated and if i switch the parent value to "B", the reasons on sheet "B" should populate. The problem is if I choose "A",then switch to "C", all of the options populate the selector.

I have tried adding a function that resets the options whenever the parent value is changed, however that resulted in my page's content not being loaded.

```
 <div class="input-field col s6">
   <select id = 'reason' onChange = "getSheet()" required>
   <option value='' disabled selected>Call Reason</option>
   <option value = '1'>1</option>
   <option value = '2'>2</option>
   <option value = '3'>3</option>
   <option value = '4'>4</option>
   <option value = '5'>5</option>
  </select>
  <label> Reason</label>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class = 'row'>

 <div class="input-field col s6">
 <select id = 'og'>
 </select>
 <label>Original Reason</label>

  </div>

  <div class="input-field col s6">
  <select id = 'real'>

 </select>
 <label>Actual Reason</label>
 </div>
 </div><!-- close row-->



// when reason is changed the orignal reason(og) and real reason(real) 
//dynaimcally change
// function that returns appropriate options based on 'reason' value 
    function getSheet(){
    var dropdown=document.getElementById('reason');
    var sheet=dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(sheet);
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(returnValues).getTasks(sheet);

    }

    // function that returns values and appends the appropriate selectors to //populate with the right values
    function returnValues(Values) {


    $( "#og" ).append(Values)
    $("#real").append(Values)
    console.log(Values)
    // re initializing selectors after generating dynamic values
    var source = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    M.FormSelect.init(source);
     }
```

I expected for my options to change based on the parent value, which they do, but the options save previous values as values available.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Please add all the code needed to reproduce this (Html, code.gs, etc). Are you deploying the script as a Web-App?

Comment: I will update code